# modal segue to a xib from a xib?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, segue, xib

I have an app that uses only xibs, no storyboards.

I have created a prompt xib that I would like to present modally (with the modal animation) from a table view controller xib (named TVC.xib) The TVC is nested in a navigation controller.

I can get the prompt to present itself, but I want it to present itself with a modal animation.  Unfortunately, the presentModalViewController has been deprecated.  What is the current option to present a view controller modally in code and have it animate the same way that modal presentations used to animate?

Here is my code: (in the TVC.m)

```
PromptViewController *promptVC = [[PromptViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PromptXib" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:promptVC];
[self.navigationController presentViewController:navVC animated:YES completion:^{
    NSLog(@"presented prompt vc");
}];
```

Ideally I could replace the method in the 3rd line with `self.navigationController presentMODALViewController`... etc, but it's deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out.  I needed to set the transition style and presentation style on the view controller that I wanted to show.  Here is my solution:

```
PromptViewController *promptVC = [[PromptViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PromptXib" bundle:nil];
promptVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
promptVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
[self presentViewController:promptVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for:

`[self presentViewController:aViewController animated:animated completion:^{}];`

But you should browse some tutorials to update the knowledge.

Comment: this is incorrect.  I understand I needed `presentViewController: animated: completion:` (see my question above where my code shows that method) but what I wanted to know was how to set the presentation modally.

Comment: @jungledev This is modern method to present view modally. First line from the documentation "Presents a view controller modally." So this is completely correct. This is exactly the same what you've said, just paraphrased.

Comment: I did notice that, but it doesn't work on its own- after all, that is why I asked the question in the 1st place.  Did you test this code without setting the presentation or transition styles?  I did, and it was not a modal segue until I set those two parameters.  It is necessary to set the transition and presentation styles to do so- so this answer is incomplete because it doesn't accomplish what I wanted to do without the additional 2 lines of code in my answer below.

Comment: @jungledev So you've meant the animation? You didn't include this word in your question. Presenting modally means something different than presenting with same animation, as old modal presentation. I'd rather say your question wasn't connected with what you really wanted.